# Powershell and FTP (again)

Tags: powershell, ftp

Is this even possible? Please help

Instead of accepting input from a file (-s:filename), I am trying to use Powershell tricks as below:

```
**$cmd = 
"OPEN server
username
password
binary
cd somedir
lcd someotherdir
mget *.dat
disconnect
quit"
function ftpCommand { ftp -i -n }
$cmd | ftpCommand**
```

Powershell ISE just shows Running script / selection, Press Ctrl + Break to stop.

Comment: Piping won't work. If this was Unix, you would have a chance using command `chat`.

Comment: Reason I am trying this is not to have files around with username password info. What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: @user114385: why not just replace the password on the fly in a temporary file?

Comment: I'm with zdan...  And along with what Pascal says you *cannot* use this method of piping in PowerShell the way you're intending above.  You want want to search for "powershell ftp" to see if anyone has shared some FTP scripts as functions or modules using .NET classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PowerShell option to perform this task a premade function already exist [Here](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/804.aspx).
http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/804.aspx

All you would need to run is:

`Get-FTPFile -Source "ftp://server/path" -Target "C:\temp" -UserName "Username" -Password "P@ssw0rd"`